# How to trim Spinner selection when selected?

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I would like to trim the user's selection in Spinner. When the user chooses his country (for example "+232    Sierra Leone") to show only "+232" when the item is selected and the spinner is closed.

Thanks in advance for your advices.

```
// I have two arrays of String that i join to make one

String[] phoneCodes ={"232", "44", "1"};
String[] countries = {"Sierra Leone", "United Kingdom", "United States"};
String[] phoneCodesCountries = new String[3];


// Here i join those two arrays, for example "+232    Sierra Leone"
for (int i = 0; i < phoneCodes.length; i++) {
    phoneCodesCountries[i] = "+" + phoneCodes[i] + "       " + countries[i];
}

// Setting the adapter to phoneCodesArray

ArrayAdapter<String> phoneCodesArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegisterActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, phoneCodesCountries);
phoneCodesArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spPhoneCodes.setAdapter(phoneCodesArray);
```

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the spinner selection by

```
mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

So in your example the value will be say +232 Sierra Leone. Now you can get the country code by splitting the whole string like this:

```
String[] split = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().split("\\+");
```

Now split[0] will have your desired result +232.

Comment: Thanks Rino, getting the selection and splitting it is quite clear to me. What I am searching for is when you click on the item "+232   Sierra Leone" to display in the closed Spinner "+232" instead of "+232   Sierra Leone".

I presume it should be in `onItemSelected`